# pdo statement always return true

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my code for deleteng data to database. even if i pass wrong 
"dataid" it still output good. i even checked the database if a data has been deleted but no row affected. but if i pass "dataid" a correct id. it deletes the data with that ID and returns good. so why else doesn't worked?

is it not the good way to check if statement executed correctly? the code im using is i found at this site. but it doesn't work for me, can someone help me thanks

```
$temp = $_POST['dataid'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_deletesignatory (?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $temp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
    $value = $stmt->execute(); 
    if($value){
        echo "good";
    }else{
        echo "error";
        }
```

Comment: Read the documentation! `http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php` clearly states that the `execute()` method returns true _if the query succeeds_. That has nothing to do with the fact if any data got selected or deleted by that query. Even if not the query has still been successfully executed. You'd have to check for selected of affected rows instead, not the return value of the `execute()` call.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the query executed normally so it returns true. Try the following using [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo "good";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```